# Coolant - meaning of label on bottle

Tags: maintenance, coolant

I am currently on vacation in Mallorca, Spain. The car (Citroën C4 Picasso running on diesel) that I am driving is running low on coolant. I went to a gas station to buy a bottle of coolant for the car. On the bottle there is a label that reads "USO DIRECTO" and "10%" (I have attached a photo of the label). "USO DIRECTO" means "direct use" according to Google Translate. What does the 10% mean? (Normally you have to mix 50% coolant with 50% water).

[image]

Comment: Does the bottle have any directions on it or is that the only label?

Comment: That is the only label on the bottle. No directions on it.

Comment: Ok. I'll see what I can dig up from that. Also, welcome to the stack! :)

Comment: That was kinda hard to find. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OKAY!**
So I found [the manufacturer's instruction page](http://www.ecoquimic.com/fichas/auto_general.html)!

Under the heading

> ANTICONGELANTE REFRIGERANTE AL 10%

They provide a "general information" section and a "directions for use" section. Based on Google Translate it says:

> Being a product formulated for this temperature should be used pure, **not** recommending its dilution. Insert directly into the circuit by the expansion vessel, or in the radiator, which has previously been emptied, it is advisable before filling, carry out a cleaning to drag the dirt and barrel that might exist in the circuit.

I'm not *100%* trusting of Google, so you can still ask someone to translate if possible.

Comment: Excellent find! +1

Comment: Thanks kyle_engineer. I really appreciate your helpfulness.

Comment: @thd no worries. :) happy to *be* helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The two words "uso directo" means it is already mixed for instant use - seen just above the 10% on the label. A pre-mixed product.

The 10% is its strength so a summer / high temperature mix - Spain is a warm country etc, Winter mixes will be a higher percentage.

Comment: I was thinking that too but I was not sure. However, it is good to see someone else interpret the label the same way as I do.